# Using @NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery with boolean IN param, 'SYS.SQLJUTL' not installed

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-annotations

**Environment**
- JavaSE 6, Oracle 11, WebSphere 7, eclipseLink 2.5.2

**Use case**
We'd like to to use

```
@NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery
```

like this:

```
@NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery
   (name = "convertToString",
    functionName = "my_schema.my_package.convert_to_string",
    parameters =
      { @PLSQLParameter(name = "p_boolean", databaseType = "BOOLEAN") },
        returnParameter = @PLSQLParameter(name = "RESULT", databaseType = "VARCHAR_TYPE"))
```

We execute then the functions like this:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("convertToString");
        query.setParameter("p_boolean", true);
        Object result = query.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println("result=" + result);
```

and/or

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("convertToInteger");
        query.setParameter("p_boolean", true);
        Object result = query.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println("result=" + result);
```

Our Oracle function implementations is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body my_schema.my_package
as
    /**
    * Converts the given boolean into an integer (true: 1, false: 0).
    * @param p_boolean boolean value to convert to an integer
    */
    function convert_to_integer
    (
        p_boolean   in boolean
    )
        return integer
    is
    begin
        if (p_boolean = true) then
            return isac_api.api_boolean_constants_pg.integer_true;
        end if;

        return isac_api.api_boolean_constants_pg.integer_false;
    end;

    /**
    * Converts the given boolean into a string (true: 'true', false: 'false').
    * @param p_boolean boolean value to convert
    */
    function convert_to_string
    (
        p_boolean   in boolean
    )
        return varchar2
    is
    begin
        if (p_boolean = true) then
            return isac_api.api_boolean_constants_pg.string_true;
        end if;

        return isac_api.api_boolean_constants_pg.string_false;
    end;
end;
```

It doesn't really work.

**Questions**

- What is the problem?
- What can we do if we are not allowed to install 'SYS.SQLJUTL' on the database BUT eclipseLink seems to use it for conversions?

Regards
Jan

Comment: "It doesn't really work" - explain, please. Is there an error message produced, or you don't get the expected results, or what..? As far as SQLJUTL goes, you've got two options - install the package, or do without whatever it is that depends on that package. Best of luck.

Comment: This isn't an EclipseLink problem, it is an issue with your query or even the function itself.  Have you tried executing it in a database client or in straight JDBC?  if you can't get it to work there, it won't work in JPA either.

Comment: The problem is we get the following error: **PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.SQLJUTL' must be declared**